# PHP Mysql SUM with decimal format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has a column : `balance_amount` of type `VARCHAR`

Now I'm facing the problem when I want to **SUM**.

*Example*:

if I have content column :

```
125,000.00
170,000.00
```

It will show just : `295`

What I want is : `295,000.00`

Comment: 125,000.00 is a string not a number

Comment: Becasue the value is stored as text and fully formatted then you are going to have a lot of problems reformatting the data for your calculations. You might want to do a table wide conversion first and stop storing is as text

Comment: View my updated answer with fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/104dd/8)

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(col,',00',''),'.','') AS SIGNED)), 2)
   AS sumOfColumn 
   FROM tab
```

Comment: Will still have problems because of the thousands comma separator: best solution is for OP to modify their column type, but you might need to stip those commas before casting

Comment: Can I set the number format into the result ? I see it just 125000. I want 125,000.00

Comment: @NoReply in each any every column you want or in result column?

Comment: This only works if the values are as specified by the OP. If you add a value like 123,456.78 then the results returned are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the thousands separator.

```
select sum(replace(column,',','')) from table;
```

Ideally though you should store numbers using an appropriate field definition and just format the numbers for display.